# Java-application log error

Tags: java, websphere

I am getting the following error once i deploy my EAR file to the server. 
    Since I am new to JAVA i am unable to figure out what could fix this issue.
Any help is much appreciated.

I have tried changing the Compiler version too, but that does not seem to help either.
Also, the error is as below.

```
[2017-10-04 14:23:24,716] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader#initWebApplicationContext


ERROR: Context initialization failed    

       org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.sl.was.cashpayment.jms.JMSApplicationListener] for bean with name 'applicationListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/applicationContext-jms.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/sl/was/cashpayment/jms/JMSApplicationListener, offset=6
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1238)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1304)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:870)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1732)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1403)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2214)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5487)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5613)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:667)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:611)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1293)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
                at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:424)
                at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
                at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
                at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
                at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
                at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
                at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
                at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1820)
                at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:558)
                at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:608)
                at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:985)
                at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1074)
                at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Comment: It's not the compiler version being the problem, it's the runtime version.

Comment: @Kayaman: Thanks for your reply. How do i change the runtime version and what file do i need to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class was compiled against a higher Java version than your server is running on.  WebSphere 7.0 and 8.0 (and 8.5, out of the box) run on Java 6, so my guess is that your class was compiled with Java 7 or above.  Java is backward-compatible but not forward-compatible - you can't run newer-spec classes on an older-spec JVM.

The simplest solution is to recompile your classes with Java 6.  Alternately, if you're running WebSphere 8.5.5, you can switch your server to run on Java 8 using the "managesdk" script in WebSphere's bin directory (assuming you installed the Java 8 package with the server).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. it would be great if you could tell me the steps on how to recompile the classes with Java 6.

Comment: That's not really feasible without knowing a lot about your build environment.  Basically, it's whatever Java version you're getting the "javac" command from - sometimes that comes from a JAVA_HOME environment variable, sometimes it's declared in the configuration of your IDE, sometimes it's in a properties file.

Comment: Hi Jarid, thanks a lot for your reply. Looks like the application that i am working on was originally compiled with 1.6 and RAD 9.6 is not compatible anymore with 1.6. Is there any other way we could build the ear file outside of rad. I am just performing a struts update to the older version of code.Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the server runs on Java version previous to a version you compiled with.
E.G compiled with java7 and server runs on java6